# Is it possible to turn a string with base64 encoded image data into a displayable image in flash lite?

Tags: flash, mobile-phones, flashlite

I have tried using a data URI to load the image data into a movie clip, but flash lite does not appear to support the data URI scheme.

I also thought it might be possible to base64 decode the image data and write it out to a file and load the file back into the movie clip using the file URI scheme.  However, I do not see a way to write to the filesystem in the documentation.  Am I missing something in the flash lite docs that would allow me to write to the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible on the client side - Flash Lite doesn't have any APIs for dealing with binary data, all you can do is read it in as an image with loadMovie.

You can probably do this on the server side though, if you find a suitable image library. Just make sure that the image is getting sent with the correct mime-type, so FL knows what it is.